# pg_dump can't write to drive C | Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Problem is just as the title says.

pg_dump literally can't write to anywhere on drive `C:` - the drive windows is installed on.

---

**More details:**

- created Temp folder on `C:` drive
- modified access - added user EVERYONE with Full Permissions
- running `pg_dump.exe --file "c:\\Temp" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --verbose --format=c --blobs "ldmgmt"`

**Result:**

```
pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not open output file "c:\\Temp": Permission denied
```

But if I change drive to `D:` - it works.

Anyone knows how to make it write to drive `C:`?

Comment: Try adding a file name to the file string for the file parameter. It is probably trying to write to a file on the c drive called temp and not to a file in the temp folder

Comment: @Aaron You are absolutely right. I can't believe I am so goddamn stupid. Oh, I should really learn to pay attention to smallest details, otherwise I'll be doomed. Thank you so much! Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept & upvote it with great pleasure.